# Mule Studio: Security components on community

Tags: components, mule, mule-studio

I would like to be able to use secure components on community version of Mule Studio, can i do it? Components like this http://www.mulesoft.com/platform/soa/mule-enterprise-security from enterprise version. How can i install then on my IDE?

Tks

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in your question: you need Mule Enterprise Edition to use Enterprise Edition features. This applies to Mule and to Studio.